# Can a getter return data from 2 different sources

Tags: javascript

can I have a getter which can match 2 different sources?

I have an array of commands.Each command is an object (JSON):

```
Commands= [{
opCode: anOpCode,
field: aField,// matching the field in html
parser: 'referenceToAfunction',
params:aParam, //the param can be null or have some value
value: null//I have a getter to that value
}, //many other commands...]
```

The ViewModel (getters from my commands):

```
    Object.defineProperty(VM, aField, {
      get: function () {
        return Commands.find(function(cmd) {
              if(cmd.field == aField)
                 return cmd.value;
             });
         }
    });
```

I have some specials commands where 2 different params match the same field in html.

In my array it will be 2 different object (where only params value is different), but I would like the getter to be updated if any of them changes

Comment: A getter can do whatever it wants to find the result.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your call to `defineProperty()`.

Comment: Did you mean `Object.defineProperty(VM, 'aField', {`?

Comment: The getter should refer to `this` so it's getting from the correct object.

Comment: i fixed the syntax error. my question isn't because my code wasn't working but more how to do that...

Comment: What is `Commands` and how does it relate to the object you're trying to get from?

Comment: What is the value of `aField` when you call `Object.defineProperty()`?

Comment: Commands is the array I defined. I have updated the question. is it understandable now ?

Comment: It's still not clear how it relates to the `VM` object. You want `VM.foo` to return the value from the element of `Commands` where `field = "foo"`?

Comment: valueofafield is null or undefined. Is getting defined on server response

Comment: that is exactly what I want. but i can have two or more elements where field=='foo'

Comment: for same field in VM, server can send notification with different params

Comment: A getter can only return one thing at a time, unless you want to return an array.

Comment: it's like an alias